# Better way to enable/disable a CCMenu object

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

> * Assertion failure in -[CCTouchDispatcher forceAddHandler:array:], /libs/cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/CCTouchDispatcher.m:108
>
> * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate already added to
>   touch dispatcher.'

The line causing it is

```
skillsMenu.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

`skillsMenu` is just a `CCMenu`. I like to enable/disable it with the above line often.

The problem is, I don't know how to interpret this error properly - I have no clue why would setting this property cause such error.

Perhaps it was wrong to use that line in the first place. Is there not a better way to enable/disable a `CCMenu`?

cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1

Comment: .touchEnabled seems very buggy in current 2.1x version of cocos2d iphone. If I switch it on/off/on and so on, after a while it just stays off despite the last call being on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isTouchEnabled` registers/unregisters the touch handler for the object.

Registering and unregistering of touch handlers in the same step has caused problems in the past, although, in more recent versions, I believe this has been fixed.

In any case, if you simply want to temporarily enable/disable a menu, it will be less problematic to enable/disable the individual menu items:

```
-(void) modifyMenu:(CCMenu*) menu withEnabledValue:(BOOL) enabled
{
    CCMenuItem *menuItem;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(menu.children, menuItem)
    {
        [menuItem setIsEnabled: enabled ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems I don't have enough rep to comment on other answers yet, but I thought I would point out that @YvesLeBorg 's answer is not valid for _Cocos2d-iphone_ _1.x_ , which is the version the OP asked about. It is, however, valid for _Cocos2d-iphone_ _2.x_ .

Comment: I use this solution on cocos2d 2.1 and menuItem continues enabled.

Answer (score 2):

CCMenu has an a .enabled property (setable), use that instead. The difference with isTouchEnabled is that the menu is not registered/deregistered from the touch dispatcher. Instead, when myMenu.enabled is false, the touches are simply ignored from the start in CCMenu's ccTouchBegan delegate method. This is cleaner, and avoids the trap of playing with isTouchEnabled (that is a property of the CCLayer class, which CCMenu extends).

Comment: I can't find this .enabled property at all :(

Comment: hmmm ... this is a 2.0 classic ! I answered too quickly on this. Until you go there, i'd look at Mark's answer above. Either do it from the outside looking in, or subclass/MODIFY CCMenu, whichever makes sense in your context.